# How can I list files with find and Perl?

Tags: bash, file, perl, directory-listing

I'm working in a HP-UX based machine and I need to list the name of the logs contained in a folder by the date and separated of the name by a ";" and the result, sorted by date in descending order this stored in a txt so the content of the txt will be like:

```
2019-02-02;/home/user/Documents/imthelog03.log
2019-02-01;/home/user/Documents/imthelog02.log
2019-01-29;/home/user/Documents/imthelog01.log
```

I've tried this:

```
find /home/user/Documents/*.log* exec perl -MPOSIX -e 'print POSIX::strftime "%Y%m%d\n", localtime((stat $ARGV[0])[9])'
```

but I can't get what I need, I can't use `stats`
I'm using a `for` to read line by line 
so How can I get the date and the `path/filename` separated by a `;` in a txt, sorted by date descending using bash and eventually perl, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can do it all in Perl

```
perl -MPOSIX=strftime -wE'$d = shift || "."; 
    say strftime("%Y-%m-%d", localtime((stat $_)[9])), "; $_" 
        for sort { (stat $b)[9] <=> (stat $a)[9] } glob "$d/*log*"
' dir-name
```

where you submit the `dir-name` to the one-liner (or it works with `.`, the current directory).

Note, I don't see a need for `find` as you're getting a listing of (log) files from a directory.

This can be optimized, to not run `stat` repeatedly, but I doubt that it matters in expected use. I would recommend putting this in a nice little script though.

---

Still, `stat` isn't cheap and if this regularly catches long file lists then use

```
perl -MPOSIX=strftime -wE'$d = shift || "."; 
    say strftime("%Y-%m-%d", localtime($_->[1])), "; $_->[0]" 
        for 
            sort { $b->[1] <=> $a->[1] } 
                map { [$_, (stat $_)[9]] } glob "$d/*log*"
' dir-name
```

where I've split the statement into yet more lines to emphasize the change.

The input file list from `glob` is used to first build another list, using `map`, with an arrayref for each filename: The name itself *and* that file's timestamp.  Then the pair-wise comparisons in `sort` don't have to run `stat` every time through; they use time-stamps precomputed once.  This is called a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform). Additionally, the `sprintf` need not run `stat` again, either.

Note that the optimization comes with an overhead, so use this only when it is indeed expected to be needed.  See, for example, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50150736/4653379) (last section) for a discussion and links.

Comment: Great day!...saw your comments on 54659691.. I have also posted an answer.. pls review and I would like to see your answer as well..

Comment: also when you get time.. pls review 54654803 and suggest improvements.. will connect later.. have a great day!

Comment: @stack0114106 As for the [first one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54659691/how-to-randomly-pick-a-region-consecutive-and-perform-it-for-a-number-of-time) -- nice solution coding wise! But not efficiency wise: (1) the file has 10 million lines (up to 1Gb), too much to slurp -- AND (2) the regex goes over all that first, to clean out those lines, and (less of a problem) (3) has to scan into that up-to-Gb string for each random number

Comment: thanks zdim.. I also felt that substring over a slurped file is expensive..

Answer (score 0):

```
find /home/user/Documents/*.log* -type f -exec perl -MPOSIX -le 'print strftime("%Y%m%d",localtime((stat $ARGV[0])[9])),";$ARGV[0]"' {} \; | sort -k1,1
```